# How to stay Logged in Firebase iOS13+

Tags: swift, firebase, logging, firebase-authentication, ios13

This question was already asked here and the solution is not relevant anymore because there are some changes in iOS13.
How can I stay logged in after closing an app and re-opening it.

I have `WelcomeViewController`, which appears when not logged in, and class `CoffeeViewController: UIViewController` which should be appear if the user is logged in.

```
class CoffeeViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkAuthn()
}

  func checkAuthn() {
             if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "welcomeScreen") as? WelcomeViewController
                    self.present(initialViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                 }
             } else {
            print("Done")
             }
         }

}
```

and I know I should implement rootview controller in `SceneDelegate` (previously it was in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method). And I don't know how to make it correctly. I tried this way but it didn't work for me.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
       let vc = CoffeeViewController()
       let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        window?.rootViewController = nc
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
    }
```

-------------------------Part 2------------------------------------------

after this changes in sceneDelegate:

```
guard let windowsScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: CoffeeViewController())
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I receive error:

[image: error]

-------------------------Part 3 Solution----------------------------------

i replaced code in sceneDelegate and it works fine.

```
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        let homeVC = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShopsMain") as! CoffeeViewController
        let navC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVC)
        window?.rootViewController = navC
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: To provide more context and show what research you have done, please provide the URLs, e.g., regarding those changes in iOS13, where you read on how to implement the rootview controller in SceneDelegate, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `window` in `UISceneDelegate`.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: CoffeeViewController())
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: i receive an Error in ViewDidLoad func. Pic in you can look at Part 2 of my question

Comment: That seems to be an entirely different issue. It means now the `rootViewController` is set to `CoffeeViewController`. So the answer worked.

Comment: on the one hand you right, but on the another it doesnt work) Without this changes it works fine.

Comment: after starting app it should download data from Firebase, but it doesnt

Comment: There are multiple errors in your code. Either you have to do a much deeper research on your issue and ask these on SO in a different post. My answer is based on the input that you've provided in your question. It suggests that you're navigating to the next view controller which is created programmatically, whereas your new issue suggests otherwise.

Comment: i've made changes in sceneDelegate and now it works.

Comment: The solution you've provided has info that was not provided in the question previously. No one could know you had created the view controller in main storyboard or that it's id is "ShopsMain". Also, please don't change the original question.

Comment: you could just say that you need a name of id Identifier.

Comment: There was no proof that view controller was in storyboard dude. The code you were trying suggested that it was created programatically.